# Making an array from 3 lists in python

Tags: python

I am just getting started in Python and is trying to get started with making an np.array out from 3 lists.

```
animals=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
analouges=["A","B","C","D"]
days=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

And i want create an array that have that animal list as the first column and the days as the first row. The analogues should loop as this, and be able to change if one of the list changes.

Example of the array I want

```
012345678
1ABCDABCD
2BCDABCDA
3CDABCDAB
4DABCDABC
5ABCDABCD
6BCDABCDA
7CDABCDAB
8DABCDABC
```

Comment: example is missing

Comment: How have you attempted to solve this?

Comment: I tried with a for loop, but got stuck with the repeat of list analogues

Comment: In my opinion, you can't use loops to generate such special events like the first row, however you can call functions to do what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
import numpy as np 

animals=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
analouges=np.array(["A","B","C","D"])
days=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
output = np.zeros((animals.size+1, days.size+1), dtype="U256")

for i in range(animals.size+1):
    analogueCount = i-1 # for keeping track of the cycling analogue index
    for j in range(days.size+1):

       # Dealing with the  rows and columns
       if i == 0 and j ==0:
           output[i, j] = str(0)
       elif i == 0:
           output[i, j] = str(days[j-1])
       elif j == 0:
           output[i, j] = str(animals[i-1])
       else:
           analogueIndex = (analogueCount + j - 1) % analouges.size
           output[i, j] =  analouges[analogueIndex]

print(output)
```

Which gives an output of

```
[['0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8']
 ['1' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D']
 ['2' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A']
 ['3' 'C' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A' 'B']
 ['4' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'C']
 ['5' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D']
 ['6' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A']
 ['7' 'C' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A' 'B']
 ['8' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A' 'B' 'C']]
```

Which I think is what you want.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: I have know tried it a bit. If my days or my animal number is more than 1 number I only get the first number. I can't figure out why? Any ideas

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by more than one number? Like more than one digit (ie 15 or something). In that case try changing the dtype of the no.zeros() to `"string_"`.

Comment: Yes exactly. I have tried changing the dtype to "string_", but it didn't work

Comment: Change the `dtype` to `"object"` or `"U256"`, depending on how long you expect the number in animals or days.